# jquery adding position fixed when div reaches top is done but how to add additional function?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have managed to get a div to change to position fixed when it reaches the top of the page as a result of this very useful answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096021/2039935.

The problem is now that when it becomes fixed the content beneath it obviously jumps up, since the div no longer pushes the rest of the content down. I need to add a top margin, the height of the div to the content below, at the point that it changes to being fixed, so the content below continues to scroll smoothly beneath the fixed div..

The code for changing the div to position fixed when reaching the top of the page is ...

```
$(function(){
var stickerTop = parseInt($('#header-container').offset().top);
$(window).scroll(function() {
$("#header-container").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-    container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
        position: 'fixed',
        top: '0px'
    } : {
        position: 'relative'
    }); 
});
});//]]>
```

Should be an easy one for those in the know..

Many thanks !

FYI The answer to this is......

```
$(function(){
    var stickerTop = parseInt($('#header-container').offset().top);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var movelisting = (parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-    container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? '200px' : '0px';
        $("#search-listings-container").css("marginTop", movelisting);

        $("#header-container").css((parseInt($(window).scrollTop()) + parseInt($("#header-container").css('margin-top')) > stickerTop) ? {
            position: 'fixed',
            top: '0px'
        } : {
            position: 'relative'
        }); 
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't a "do this for me" forum. What have you tried so far? SO is a place for problems to he solved, not additional functionality added for you

Comment: can you show in a jsfiddle or jsbin,etc you progress thus far.
there's other ways to do what you are trying to accomplish, so if i could see your progress i can help you out there.
and dont mind bojangles

Comment: If we're talking about wasting comments, your reply was longer... Anyway, no, I don't feel "big". I think you've overreacted massively; I was stating that you should not ask SO users to finish things for you. There's no _problem_ here, just a lack of will to work this out yourself. Google is a fantastic resource...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that underestand what's your problem. I see that you have a div that starts being position: relative; and ends fixed. This causes an effect to the next div below. Maybe you can try to put some margin-top to this div `$('#id_div').css({'margin-top':'40px'});` after assign a fixed position to the #header-container.

I've put 40px but the you've to put the height value you believe it.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I am trying to do but not able to get the 
$('#id_div').css({'margin-top':'40px'});
to trigger simultaneously with the position : fixed ?

Comment: And with .css({'top':'Xpx'});? not with margin-top

Comment: I make this example, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/newpatriks/ESu5B/) what your are looking for? :)